# SecurityException with PdfRenderer, comes with password protected pdfs, and than repeats even with normal pdfs

Tags: android, pdf, pdfrenderer, android-securityexception

If trying to open Password Protected PDF with **PdfRenderer** API, gives **SecurityException** and handled accordingly, inside catch block and then**onDestroy** basic clean up is done, and comes back to home activity and then navigating a simple non-protected PDF than again the same exception occurs.

Please note, this happens only once any protected file got opened.

Refer below code:

```
      @Override
    protected PdfRenderer doInBackground(Uri... uri) {
        Uri uriToProcess = uri[0];
        try {
            contentResolver=getContentResolver();
            parcelFileDescriptor = contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(uriToProcess, "r");
            if(parcelFileDescriptor!=null && mPdfRenderer==null) {
                mPdfRenderer = new PdfRenderer(parcelFileDescriptor);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            exceptionMsg="Sorry! No such file or directory found";
            handleExceptionInUI(exceptionMsg, progressDialog);
            Log.e("$$$$ FNFException", e.toString());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            exceptionMsg="Sorry! Something went wrong with IO";
            handleExceptionInUI(exceptionMsg, progressDialog);
            Log.e("$$$$ IOException", e.toString());
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            if (parcelFileDescriptor!=null) {
                try {
                    parcelFileDescriptor.close();
                    parcelFileDescriptor = null;
                    contentResolver=null;
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if (mPdfRenderer!=null){
                mPdfRenderer.close();
                mPdfRenderer=null;
            }

            exceptionMsg="Password protected file, This can't be opened";
            handleExceptionInUI(exceptionMsg, progressDialog);
            Log.e("$$$$ SecurityException", e.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            exceptionMsg="Sorry! Something went wrong.";
            handleExceptionInUI(exceptionMsg, progressDialog);
            Log.e("$$$$ EXCEPTION", e.toString());
        }
        return mPdfRenderer;
    }
```

Any help cordially appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my app. The way I solved it was using an https://github.com/TomRoush/PdfBox-Android and load the document and check for password protection. After no InvalidPasswordException has been thrown the file can be safely loaded with the PdfRenderer.